# IntelliJ 13 won't resolve Compass SASS libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, compass-sass

I'm using IntelliJ 13.0.2 for a web project using Compass for my style sheets. The SCSS editor won't resolve Compass mixins, variables, etc. for auto-completion and syntax checking. (And the issue is purely the editor: the automatic compilation of SCSS to CSS works just fine using the File Watcher plugin.)

It seems that the Compass binary finds the Compass libraries just fine but IntelliJ doesn't and I don't see how I can tell IntelliJ where they live. I'm sure this all boils down to helping IntelliJ get past the @import statement. These are underlined in red with a tool-tip that says **Cannot resolve import**:

`@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";`

Normally, I'd think the answer is to put an absolute path but Compass is finding things so is there a thing like a search path for SCSS that IntelliJ will understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With perfect timing, I asked this on the day IntelliJ 13.1 was released which fixes the problem. I did have to reenable Compass support in my project preferences for some reason.

Comment: And it seems like every time I re-open the project, I have to reenable the Compass support checkbox in the project settings. I guess this is a bug.

Comment: I have same issue, I have to re-enable compass, I'm on 13.1.1 - but I haven't downloaded the latest updates yet

Comment: It seems this was finally fixed for me in 13.1.3. It was tiresome to constantly re-enable this.